# Error while dealloc NSManagedObjectContext of the view controller for adding scene, but ok for edit scene

Tags: core-data, automatic-ref-counting, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two controllers, one is called as AddressesController

```
@interface AddressesController : UITableViewController<ManageAddressDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@end
```

which display addresses by NSFetchedResultsController normally, and perform SegueAddAddress for user action, such as:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SegueNewAddress sender:sender];
}
```

and perform SegueEditAddress when click a row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Address *address = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SegueEditAddress sender:address];
}
```

Another controller is EditAddressController, and it's the destinationViewController of both SegueAddAddress and SegueEditAddress:

```
@interface EditAddressController : UITableViewController<EZFormDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) Address *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ManageAddressDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

I will prepare the segue for sub controller with an address in sub NSManagedObjectContext named as editContext in AddressesController#prepareForSegue:sender
(setup delegate protocol also)

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueEditAddress]) {
    EditAddressController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.delegate = self;
    NSManagedObjectContext *editContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    editContext.MR_workingName = @"Edit Address Context";
    [editContext setParentContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
    Address *address = sender;
    Address *editAddress = [address inContext:editContext];
    controller.address = editAddress;
    controller.context = editContext;
}
```

prepare a new address in addingContext for adding also:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:SegueNewAddress]) {
    EditAddressController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.delegate = self;
    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    addingContext.MR_workingName = @"Adding Address Context";
    [addingContext setParentContext:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
    Address *newAddress = [Address createInContext:addingContext];
    controller.address = newAddress;
    controller.context = addingContext;
}
```

When user click save button in EditAddressController, and it will callback the delegate(AddressesController) with below code after fill address properties:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate controller:self save:self.address];
}
```

And the origin AddressesController will handle the new or edit action by the same callback function:

```
- (void)controller:(EditAddressController *)controller save:(Address *)address {
    NSArray *keys = @[@"username", @"phone", @"zipcode", @"street"];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [address dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
    void (^success)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [address importValuesForKeysWithObject:[responseObject JSONValue]];
        [address.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };
    void (^failure)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        DDLogError(@"Failed to create address because of: %@", error);
    };

    if (address.id == nil || address.id.intValue == 0) {
        [self.http postPath:@"addresses" parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
    } else {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addresses/%@", address.id];
        [self.http putPath:path parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
    }
}
```

This function is just post the new or edited address to the server and save it into CoreData after http ok.
I use Magical Record to perform CoreData related operation
and above code **[address.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];"** will caused the default context be saved also.
and I have tried to use normal [NSManagedObjectContext:save:error], the error is the same.

The problem is, though the adding and edit logic is as same by 99%, but It's ok for editing.
When I add an address, it will be saved to db, and raise an exception when **[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]** is called, error occurred when EditAddressController dealloc the ivar ***context***:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x3)

the error stack comes with(list some key function only):

```
[NSPersistStoreCache decrementRefCountForObjectID]
... 
[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) managedContextDidUnregisterObjectsWithIDs:]
...
[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc]
```

Comment: After some tests, I found the most important difference between two case is the address object, new address associated context seems has been 'binded' and reject any 'release/dealloc' attempts.

Answer (score 0):

After several rounds test, I found the root cause:

We should send a reset message to the managed object context after below message:

```
[address.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

[address.managedObjectContext reset];
```

And I have no idea about why editing object won't cause error.